# Floating top-right and top-left and wordwrapping

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a webpage which should contain an `<h1>` heading to the upper left and a horizontal list to the upper right. There is no width specified for either of the elements. The problem that I cannot seem to fix is that in case the content of the `<h1>` grows to long I would like for it to wrap. But no matter how I try the list is pushed down to the next row when the content grows to long. Help would be much appreciated.

Preferably I would like to use to the following markup:

```
<div>
    <h1><a href="#">A header which should wrap and leave the list unaffected</a></h1>
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

For the positioning I currently use the following styles:

```
h1 {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:left
}

ul { float:right }

li {
    float:left;
    list-style-type: none
}
```

In case anyone is helped by it I have created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sj5SW/

Comment: I think you'd have to give it a `max-width` property, in % would be good to use. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sj5SW/3/)

Comment: That would work if I knew the max-width of the list but not in this case where I don't :-(

Comment: You would simply give both an approximate max width. Take for an example a list that ends up taking 95% of the window: What do you want to be done with it then?

Comment: I am afraid that will not work. As long as either element do not wrap I am OK with both a 10% 90% and a 90% 10% split. But in case there must be wrapping, I want it to be the h1 that wraps.

Comment: you could also try to use flexbox: http://jsfiddle.net/fHZyR/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in the jsfiddle

Updated code:

```
h1 {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

ul { float:right }

li {
    float:left;
    list-style-type: none
}


<div>
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
    <h1><a href="#">A header which should wrap and leave the list unaffected</a></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: That would solve it. But should it not be possible without altering the markup order? I would like e.g. screen readers to read the heading first.

Comment: http://accessibility.psu.edu/readorderhtml recommends against any floating elements for this reason.  However, they also tipped me off that if you set "visibility:hidden", screen readers won't read your text.  So, here's a little hack http://jsfiddle.net/rGswZ/.